# why did not display this data in blade.php file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

hellow, I have edit.blade.php file in Laravel

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@if (isset($permission))
<div>
<p>Hellow Friends</p>
</div>
@endif
<h1>Hi</h1>
@stop
```

but did not display

Hellow friend

words. only dispaly @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
and

## Hi

how can I display Hellow Friends

Answer (score 0):

While rendering the view in controller just do:

```
$data['permission'] = true;
return view('view_name',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sent permission variable from the controller. The condition here fails is `$permission` does not exist so basically `Hellow Friends` will not be echoed.

In your controller you can do the following:

`return view('edit', ['permission' => 'whatever_you_want_here']);`

and then check for the permission in the blade file.